# Java Swing: Choosing the correct LayoutManager

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm building a PropertyPanel. Currently I'm using a `GridLayout` to manage the `JLabels` and their corresponding fields where I can specify the value. But the problem is that the `GridLayout` automatically manages the size of the columns: it makes them the same width.

This means when I'm having a big value field, the colum, is getting bigger (which is good), but the other column (with all my `JLabel`s) is getting bigger as well. Here is a screenshot:

[image]     **< BAD**

As you can see, the `image` property has a huge value, which makes both columns bigger, and I'm having a lot of space after the `JLabel`s.

So, I'm searching for a `LayoutManager` which makes each column as big as necessary.
I want a layout like this (it's edited with Gimp):

[image]     **< GOOD**

Thanks

Comment: why not use two separate panels, each with its own `GridLayout`?

Comment: @mre: I don't know... But the whole propertypanel should be resizable.

Comment: then place both aforementioned panels on another panel. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SpringLayout for this. See [How to Use SpringLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html).

Example layout:

[image]

Remember that you also can nest layouts.

Comment: +1, probably the better solution, although I'm unfamiliar with this layout.

Answer (score 2):

`SpringLayout` is what I typically use for forms like this.  Although I think `GridBagLayout` would also work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to try to hack everything by mixing GridLayout and BorderLayout, so maybe it's not the best solution but...

Create two GridLayouts, both have a single column.  One for the labels the other for the controls.

Now create a BorderLayout to be the parent.

Add the left grid to the BorderLayout.WEST and the right grid to the BorderLayout.CENTER.

Comment: @Rocky Triton, +1 that's basically what I was suggesting, but I left the implementation details up to OP. And I wouldn't necessarily call it "hacking".

Comment: I think if cell heights differ you will get very strange effects using two GrigLayouts.

Comment: The only problem with this is that if a component is larger on one row your labels will not line up correctly.

Comment: @Rocky: Thanks for the idea! But I'll go for the `SpringLayout`.

Comment: @mre I call it hacking because the better way would probably be to use the GridBagLayout, but after 12+ years of doing java development I have still avoided to learn how to use it properly.

Comment: @martin: Yes that's probably the better solution, I've never even tried that layout.

Answer (score 2):

While this was answered 11 hours ago, I just thought I'd pop in & make a suggestion.  I suggest [GroupLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/groupExample.html).

I was looking to break from nested layouts for a name/value dialog recently and looked at both `GroupLayout` & `SpringLayout`.  It seemed the only advantage offered by `SpringLayout` was that it could achieve the right aligned text of the labels (there may be a way to do it using GL, but I couldn't figure out how).  On the downside, the Java Tutorial examples for `SpringLayout` used a whopping 'helper class' to define layout constraints.

In the end (it was only a very short 'study') I chose to use `GroupLayout`.

Comment: hmmm yout NestedLayout ???, really I'm not fans of stick all JComponents to the one Container for most complex GUI .... and now let's find better LayoutManager for that :-) maybe +1

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).  If constrained within the current JDK, [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an overview of the standard LayoutManagers:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

You could e.g. use GridBagLayout or the non-standard MigLayout, if you want to code the GUI by hand.

If you want to use a GUI builder (e.g. the one in NetBeans) you could use the GroupLayout.